# C: perror, stdout output order

Tags: c, stdout, stderr

### Code

```
printf("Doing functionname... ");
if (functionname(args) == -1)
{
    perror("functionname");
}
else
{
    printf("ok\n");
}
```

### Expected behavior

> Doing functionname... ok

OR

> Doing functionname... functionname: Error blah blah

### Actual behavior

However *stderr* and *stdout* are different output streams so the result looks like this,

> functionname: Error blah blah
>
> Doing functionname...

What are the possible workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flush the output stream. `stdout`, by default, is line buffered; so the output is only effectivelly written when it sees a '\n' (or when the buffer gets filled). By contrast, `stderr` is not buffered by default, so every single character is output immediately.

```
printf("blah blah blah");
fflush(stdout);
```

If you terminate the string with a '\n', the stream will be flushed with no need for a specific fflush statement.

```
printf("blah blah blah\n"); /* stream flushed */
```

---

Alternatively, print your information stuff to the `stderr` stream

```
fprintf(stderr, "Doing functioname...");
```

This has the advantage that users may redirect all information messages to /dev/null

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
```

Make sure there are no intervening library calls (or save `errno` if there are).

`strerror` is in `<string.h>`.